# Typescript: TypeError: Cannot read property 'yc' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**The problem**

I am tinkering with reusable form controls in Angular following mainly [a guide](https://coryrylan.com/blog/building-reusable-forms-in-angular) i found on google. It is working as intended with a minor problem though, i am getting an TypeError from outside my own code: 
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHd81.png). Weirdly enough i only get an error prompt when entering letters and numbers, when deleting (as in hitting backspace) no error occurs. The validation and all other functions work as intended though.

**What i tried**

So far tired to catch a value that is null with logs that might cause this error, without luck so far. Pinpointing the error has been a problem since i cant find documentation what the proerties yc and T are in the inner workings of javascript. Hence i dont exactly know what i am fishing for.

**Angular code**

[Repository can be found here](https://github.com/Dachshund77/ExamFour/tree/SOquestion)


**The surrounding parent component**

create-team-page.componenet.html

```
<form [formGroup]="createTeamForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
<app-create-team-form formControlName="team"></app-create-team-form>
<button>Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

The TS file for the parent

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms'
    import { Team } from 'src/app/shared/models/team/team';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-team-page',
  templateUrl: './create-team-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-team-page.component.css']
})
export class CreateTeamPageComponent implements OnInit {

  createTeamForm : FormGroup

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createTeamForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      team: []
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  submit() {
    console.log(this.createTeamForm.value);
  }  
}
```

**FormControl child used int parent**

HTML file of the child

```
<div [formGroup]="form">

<label for="teamName" i18n="Input label | Label for the team input"> Enter Team Name</label>
<input formControlName="teamName" id="teamName" type="text" placeholder="Test" i18n-placeholder="Team name placeholder | Placeholder fot the team name input"></div>
```

TS file of the child, here is the majority of the logic

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validator, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export interface CreateTeamFormValues {
  teamName: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-team-form',
  templateUrl: './create-team-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-team-form.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CreateTeamFormComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CreateTeamFormComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CreateTeamFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {

  //I would like to use the model directly?
  form: FormGroup;
  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  onChange: any = () => { console.log('ON CHANGE');
  };
  onTouched: any = () => {  console.log('ON TOUCH');
};

  get value(): any {
    return this.form.value;
  }

  set value(value: any) {
    console.log('SET VALUE');
    console.log(value);

    this.form.setValue(value);
    this.onChange(value);
    this.onTouched();
  }

  get teamNameControl() {
    return this.form.controls.teamName;
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    // create the inner form
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      teamName: ['',Validators.required],
    });

    this.subscriptions.push(
      // any time the inner form changes update the parent of any change
      this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        this.onChange(value);
        this.onTouched();
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    console.log('REGISTER CHANGES');
    console.log(this.form)

    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    console.log('WRITE VALUE');

    if (value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    if (value === null) {
      this.form.reset();
    }
  }


  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    console.log('REGISTER TOUCHED');
    console.log(this.form)

    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  // communicate the inner form validation to the parent form
  validate(_: FormControl) {
    console.log('VALIDATE');
    console.log(this.form.valid);
    return this.form.valid ? null : { team: { valid: false } };
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    isDisabled ? this.form.disabled : this.form.enabled;
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

It seem that this error only occurs in chrome, so maybe it is an issue with that. I haved tested with firefox and edge and there i dont get an error.

Comment: @Chellappanவ Should be inistalised in the constructor, with the formBuilder. Unless im missinterpreting your question.

Comment: @Chellappanவ as you can see the the formControl (should unless im mistaken) be initalised with:
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      teamName: ['',Validators.required],
    });
I clarified the post slightly.

Comment: Sorry it was my misunderstanding , you have implemented correctly only. Can you try to remove this {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CreateTeamFormComponent),
      multi: true
    } from custom form control and check?

Comment: Tested it, makes no difference. The point of the snippet is to tell Angular that this formGroup is self validating and can inform its parent of its state.

Answer (score 0):

So as usual the problem is in front of the screen. Turns out chrome was slightly outdated. Lessons learned.

So for anyone stumbling over this post; make sure everything is up to date before searching for a way more unlikely problem.